# Ajax login page returning html tags

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to make a simple login page using ajax and php. the response text it is returning is like this: 
responseText :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
success
```

Why is this happening? How can I get rid of these html tags.
my code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
<label>Username</label><input type="text" id="username" name="user">
<label>Password</label><input type="text" id="password" name="pwd">
<input type="button" onclick="sub()" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
            <script>
            function sub()
            {
            var email=$("#username").val();
            var password=$("#password").val();
            var dataString = 'email='+email+'&password='+password;
            if($.trim(email).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0)
            {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            url: "home1.php",
            data: "username=" + $("#username").val()+"&password=" +    $("#email").val(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(status){
                alert(status);
            }
            });

            }
                        }
</script>
```

home1.php:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
session_start();
if(isSet($_POST['email']) && isSet($_POST['password']))
{
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']); 
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

$result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT user_id FROM customers WHERE email1='$email' and password='$password'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if($count==1)
{
$_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];
echo "success";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: People could help better if your code was formatted correctly

Comment: You'll probably also want to include the source of the PHP file since it is what's returning the markup.

Comment: what's the relation to php here? Plus, there's no `email` ID anywhere.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I guess is the usage of home1.php

Comment: What's inside *home1.php* page? That's the one which is causing this issue.

Comment: @Rhopercy No idea. I will "guess" though; they don't have a webserver/PHP installed or accessing as `file:///`. Probably what the problem/question is about. Other than that; I've no idea.

Comment: I included the source of php file as you guys asked.. @George H Thank you guys for taking your time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your home1.php page must return a text, if you want alert(status) to work properly.

Possibly, those tags might be inserted by your web server because you did not set the Content-Type properly.

```
<?php
// home1.php

    Header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf8');
    die("This is the response");
```

The above should work with your code.

For a more advanced example, try removing the datatype 'text' and using JSON:

```
 success: function(response) {
     if (response.hasOwnProperty('status')) {
         // We should actually check there is a message property too...
         alert(response.message);
     } else {
         alert('Incorrect response received');
     }
 }
```

and in home1.php start with a file containing just:

```
<?php
    $response = array(
        'status'  => 'success',
        'message' => 'Everything is OK!',
    );
    Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');
    die(json_encode($response));
```

to see whether it all works.

## Also

You're using jQuery, so you can save some coding:

```
function sub() {
        var email=$("#username").val();
        var password=$("#password").val();
        var dataString = 'email='+email+'&password='+password;
        if($.trim(email).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0) {
            $.post(
                'home1.php',
                {
                    username: email,
                    password: password
                }
            ).done(function(response) {
                // Here response is the JSON object returned by home1.php
            });
```

Comment: Tried adding 
Header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf8');
 die("This is the response");
Still not working. Even tried it with json.. no luck there too.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this

```
$('#myform').submit( function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var username = $.trim($("#username").val()),
      password = $("#password").val();//don't trim passwords

  if (username.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "home1.php",
      data: { pUsername: username, pPassword: password }
    }).done(function( data ) {
      alert(data); //shows all data received from home1.php
    });
  }
});
```